# IIS cache all files with a certain extension using web.config

Tags: http, caching, iis, web-config, server

In my web config I have it caching everything in a certain folder like so

```
 <location path="img">
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

However my css and js are not in certain folders, I would like to be able to use wildcards like this:

`*.js,*.css,*.png,*.jpg`

is there any way to do that in IIS from the web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my use case, I want to cache all static files apart from html. (This is sometimes called cache busting)

In order for this to work, the html files cannot be part of `staticContent`. adding a new handler for html files prevents them from being permanently cached.

```
    <staticContent>
        <clientCache httpExpires="Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" />
    </staticContent>
    <handlers>
      <add
        name="HtmlHandler"
        path="*.html"
        verb="*"
        type="System.Web.Handlers"
        preCondition="integratedMode"
      />
    </handlers>
```